# how to edit the cluster function from matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab. Now I have the task to re-write the cluster function from bioinformatics tool box. After typing edit cluster in the command line, I get a the default cluster function as follows.

```
function T = cluster(Z, varargin)
%CLUSTER Construct clusters from a hierarchical cluster tree.
```

What I want is the cluster function with the following syntax.

```
cluster (phytree)

Validate clusters in phylogenetic treeexpand all in page
Syntax
LeafClusters = cluster(Tree, Threshold)
[LeafClusters, NodeClusters] = cluster(Tree, Threshold)
[LeafClusters, NodeClusters, Branches] = cluster(Tree, Threshold)
cluster(..., 'Criterion', CriterionValue, ...)
cluster(..., 'MaxClust', MaxClustValue, ...)
cluster(..., 'Distances', DistancesValue, ...)
```

Does anyone know what shall I do then? I truly appreciate your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want. If you want us to write the code, then unfortunately the question is off-topic. However, I'll answer how to get that function to return multiple variables

---

To make cluster return different things you can do it 2 ways.

One of them is to define all the possible outputs of the function as

```
function [LeafClusters,NodeClusters,Branches] = cluster(Z, varargin)
```

And then inside the function assign to those variables the values you want.

Another method is to use [`varargout`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html). This lets you define any amount of output arguments. The syntax would be:

```
function [LeafClusters,varargout] = cluster(Z, varargin)
```

And then you can go assigning `varargout` any amount of outputs, generally dependant on the `varargin` arguments (e.g.`'Criterion'`)

you should assign the arguments as a cell array:

```
vargout{5}="banana"
```

Comment: thanks very much for your kind reply. I am not asking for help with the code. I was more concerned with the pseudocode for the cluster function. I am struggling to find out the exact implementation of the default cluster function, not to mention what the function is doing there. I thought matlab is easy to learn, but now it seems like it is not so easy.

Comment: @study Matlab is easy to learn. What you are strugling is with a difficult algorithm, and that is language independent. You REALLY don't preffer a C implementation of cluster over Matlab, trust me.

Comment: thanks very much for your kind reply. So, what is the usual way to get the default functions in matlab ? Use the command edit cluster to get the cluster function ? Can this be used to get all the cluster function? Thanks again.